# Almacenamiento de horarios en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Necesito almacenar el horario de atención de una empresa. E.g. Lunes a Viernes de 8 a 16 hrs

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS horario (
  emp_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  lunes TINYINT NOT NULL,
  martes TINYINT NOT NULL,
  miercoles TINYINT NOT NULL,
  jueves TINYINT NOT NULL,
  viernes TINYINT NOT NULL,
  sabado TINYINT NOT NULL,
  domingo TINYINT NOT NULL,
  apertura VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  cierre VARCHAR(5) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Estoy pensando almacenar los días de la semana que se abre y un horario general.

- ¿De qué manera podría almacenar esta información para que pueda ser consumida e interpretada en diferentes idiomas?

> Es decir, tendría que almacenar los días de la semana en que abren y su horario

Comment: ¿Cómo pretendes usar la información? Es diferente si querés solo mostrar un cartel con el horario a que si lo querés usar para habilitar o no ciertas funciones del sistema.

Answer (score 0):

No veo correcta dicha estructura pues a cada día de la semana le estas asignando una columna; es decir

- Una sola columna que almacene los días
- Una columna que almacene el horario de inicio de atención
- Una columna que almacene el horario de término de atención
- Manejar el tipo de dato adecuado para los horarios, teniendo disponible `TIME`

Puedes revisar esta estructura básica

```
CREATE TABLE horarios(
  id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
  dia VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
  horarioApertura TIME,
  horarioCierre TIME
);
```

Almacenando los datos de este modo:

```
INSERT INTO horarios(dia, horarioApertura, horarioCierre)
VALUES
("Lunes", "09:00:00", "18:00:00"),
("Martes", "09:00:00", "18:00:00"),
("Miercoles", "09:00:00", "18:00:00"),
("Jueves", "09:00:00", "18:00:00"),
("Viernes", "09:00:00", "18:00:00"),
("Sábado", "09:00:00", "13:00:00"),
("Domingo", "09:00:00", "13:00:00");
```

Visualzándolos de este modo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Usar el tipo de dato `TIME` te va a permitir realizar cálculos de diferencia de tiempos entre dos horarios con la función [TIMEDIFF](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff), obteniendo algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Esto me parece que se puede aplicar para cuando es el horario de una empresa, yo necesito almacenar el horario de N empresas.

Comment: ok @akko modificaré pero toma en cuenta que este detalle de **N** empresas no lo mencionas en tu pregunta

Answer (score 0):

Ya que usas InnoDB que te parece si atomizas la tabla de horario, supongamos que tienes tu tabla de empresas asi :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS empresa (
  emp_id INT NOT NULL,
  nombre VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (emp_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Creamos un catalogo de dias asi :

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dia (
  dia_id INT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  dia VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (dia_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

y horario lo hacemos asi:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS horario (
  horario_id INT NOT NULL,
  dia_id INT INT NOT NULL,
  apertura TIME NOT NULL,
  cierre TIME NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (horario_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (dia_id) REFERENCES dia(dia_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Entonces tus horarios y empresas asi:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS horarioempresa (
  horarioempresa_id INT NOT NULL,
  emp_id INT INT NOT NULL,
  horario_id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (horarioempresa_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (emp_id) REFERENCES empresa(emp_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (horario_id) REFERENCES horario(horario_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

De esta manera ahorras espacio ya que no almacenas muchas veces la cadena "LUNES" y aprovechas InnoDB, ademas de que puedes hacer cosas como, si una empresa tiene el mismo horario
utilizas el mismo para las dos. Por ejemplo la empresa "A" abre los lunes de 8 a 16 hrs y la empresa "B" tambien, pues 
asi solo relacionas en horarioempresa "A" con el horario que tenga la llave foranea del dia lunes y apertura en 8 y cierre a las  16 y con "B" haces lo mismo usando la misma llave del horario.

Pude parecer mas complejo pero si estas usando Bases Relacionales así queda propiamente normalizada.